# Как организовать систему вывода средств cо счёта сайта?

Tags: php

Есть много систем как оплатить какую-нибудь услугу (paypal,робокасса), а вот как отдать деньги за выполнение данной услуги я не нашел, прошу помощи...

Comment: qiwi, webmoney, visa, yandex.money... короче электронные деньги это называется. Или я не угадал вопрос? Сформулируйте лучше.

Comment: угадали, только мне нужна система в которой заключаються все отслаьные платежные сиситемы

Comment: смотри в сторону скриптов обменников

Comment: @good: в которой заключаются _все_ остальные платёжные системы? Таких нету, откуда им взяться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос для Яндекса / Google: "Платёжный агрегатор"

У каждого из них есть своё API, используя которое сайт и будет обменивать информацией с агрегатором.

Comment: Именно это наверное ему и нужно) +1

Answer (score 1):

[@good](/users/7736/good) для начала вы должны быть зарегистрированы в каждой из систем с которыми планируете работать!

Далее иметь достаточно привилегий для проведения описаных вами действий, к примеру в системе webmoney у вас должен быть *Персональный атестат*.

И на последок, обращаетесь в службы поддержки каждой из систем и узнаете как и что делается!